# APEX trigger with CRON job to check on a custom field

Tags: apex, trigger, query, scheduled-apex, cron

Using the Apex Schedule documentation on Salesforce I have created the following APEX code:

```
global class CheckingDate implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
        List<Contacts> contacts = [SELECT Id, selected_date__c];
       If selected_date__c > d then selected_checkbox__c = 'False'  
           else selected_checkbox__c = 'True'
    }  
}
date d = system.today() .addDays(-10;)
system.Schedulable(0 0 0 1/1 * ? *)
```

Essentially I need a daily job that checks the **selected_date__c** custom date field in contacts and sees if its over 10 days old - if it is then it deselects the **selected_checkbox__c** checkbox

This will need to run daily at midnight to check if any of those dates meet the "older than 10 days" criteria.

I just wanted to check with an expert to see if this will run/ on the right path to create this - especially with the SELECT query: Do I need to add more objects here? Can you suggest improvements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you should place your conditions into the query condition so you're only touching records you want:

```
SELECT Selected_Checkbox__c
FROM Contact 
WHERE (Selected_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:10 AND 
       Selected_Checkbox__c = TRUE) OR
      (Selected_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:10 AND
       Selected_Checkbox__c = FALSE)
```

This query finds all records that should be checked but are not, or those that are that should not.

Secondly, you should design your code to expect more than 10,000 rows of data, which means you also need the Batchable interface. Here's your revised code:

```
global class CheckingDate implements Schedulable, Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    global void execute(SchedulableContext context) {
        Database.executeBatch(this);
    }
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
            [SELECT Selected_Checkbox__c
             FROM Contact 
             WHERE (Selected_Date__c < LAST_N_DAYS:10 AND 
                    Selected_Checkbox__c = TRUE) OR
                   (Selected_Date__c = LAST_N_DAYS:10 AND
                    Selected_Checkbox__c = FALSE)]
        );
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Contact[] records) {
        for(Contact record: records) {
            record.Selected_Checkbox__c = !record.Selected_Checkbox__c;
        }
        update records;
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've made a few changes to your class below. First, unlike a batch class, a Schedulable doesn't use an iterator unless you also have it implement batchable. For that reason, the results of your query don't give you a query pointer. If you have a great number of records, you'll want to implement batchable in this too so it does this in smaller blocks.

I've also moved your logic into a separate public class of its own that's called from the execute method. Also, note the change in the variable name from `ctx` to `sc` which is the convention and what the method expects to see.

Your `date d` variable needs to be declared either before your execute method or inside of your class from which it executes. Declaring it after where it's needed will cause a variable not found error at compile time since it doesn't exist.

I assume you want to schedule this class to run every day through the `System.Schedule` method with your chron expression rather than letting it schedule new instances of itself using a finish method. In either case, you'll find a number of questions in the forum about schedulables that have been stuck when updates are performed by salesforce or pushed from a sandbox by the user. To avoid that, it's preferable to declare the class as virtual and run new instances of it.

Your code omitted the for loop that you need to use to iterate on the results of your query which I've inserted into your code.  You also need to update the results of your query at the end of the loop.

While writing this, I see that sfdcfox has answered this too and I agree with him that you'll want to limit the number of records in your query to those that are in the range you're wanting to update. As is stated earlier, it's not clear how many records you're trying to update, but a batchable is preferable. Assuming you don't need to batch it, this would be what you existing class would look like as a virtual class.

```
global virtual class CheckingDate implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

       CheckDate();
    }

    public void CheckDate(){    
        date d = system.today() .addDays(-10;)
        List<Contacts> Records = [SELECT Id, selected_date__c];
        for(Contact r:Records){
           If(r.selected_date__c < d){ 
              r.selected_checkbox__c = 'True';  
           }else If(r.selected_checkbox__c != 'False'){  // this can optionally be omitted
              r.selected_checkbox__c = 'False';
           }
        }
        update Records;  
    }  

    // Optionally add a finish method that schedules a new instance of the class to run the following day at the same time

}
```